# How to get current year on cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cql, cassandra-3.0

How can I get just a part of the current date in Cassandra? In my particular case I need to get just the year.

I got to this for the moment `select dateof(now()) from system.local;`

But I could not find any function to get just the year in the documentation
https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/cql/cql/cql_reference/refCqlFunction.html#refCqlFunction__toTimestamp

I'm new with Cassandra so this maybe a silly question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *safe* way, would be to return a timestamp and parse-out the year client-side.

Natively, Cassandra does not have any functions that can help with this.  However, you can write a user-defined function (UDF) to accomplish this:

First, user defined functions are disabled by default.  You'll need to adjust that setting in your cassandra.yaml and restart your node(s).

```
enable_user_defined_functions=true
```

**NOTE: This setting is defaulted this way for a reason.  Although Cassandra 3.x has some safeguards in-place to protect against malicious code, it is a good idea to leave this turned-off unless both you need it and you know what you are doing.  And even then, you'll want to keep an eye on UDFs that get defined.**

Now I'll create my function using Java, from within cqlsh:

```
cassdba@cqlsh:stackoverflow> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION year (input DATE)
RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT RETURNS TEXT
LANGUAGE java AS 'return input.toString().substring(0,4);';
```

Note that there are a number of ways (and types) to query the current date/time:

```
cassdba@cqlsh:stackoverflow> SELECT todate(now()) as date,
    totimestamp(now()) as timestamp, now() as timeuuid FROm system.local;

 date       | timestamp                       | timeuuid
------------+---------------------------------+-------------------------------------
 2017-12-20 | 2017-12-20 21:18:37.708000+0000 | 58167cc1-e5cb-11e7-9765-a98c427e8248

(1 rows)
```

To return just only year, I can call my `year` function on the `todate(now())` column:

```
SELECT stackoverflow.year(todate(now())) as year FROm system.local;

 year
------
 2017

(1 rows)
```